# I'm trying to set a generic element invisible by attribute and in one line of javascript

Tags: javascript, hidden, visible

I'm limited to one line because of a Chrome Extension and it's the only one that fits my needs.

The `<td>` needs to be gone through to the attribute "UserName" to determine if a blocked user needs to be invisible.

I cannot figure this out and I'm really a noob when it comes to Javascript (not my language)

I've tried `display:none` `hidden` and `style.visibility="hidden"`.

I've tried w3Schools and searched through Javascript and HTML pages for how to this and while I've got code that does work, it's a script that takes about 8 lines which doesn't work. I may have to ditch it but I figured I've give it one last shot.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getAttribute("theUserName").value("madmax").style.visible = "hidden";
```

Expected - The `<td>` should not show up
Results - It shows up

Comment: You simply cannot accomplish this with one statement because property access doesn't return a reference to the DOM element for a second property to be accessed (chaining). Also, attributes don't have a `.value` property and even if they did, `value` is a property, not a method, so it can't take an argument. Additionally, `td` elements don't have a `theUserName` attribute. There is just so much wrong with what you are doing here.

Comment: Damn, and thanks for the edit. Can you do it in two? The extension does not like variables but I can give it a shot - it's Codify - The Code Adder.

Comment: Doesn't make sense that you are limited to only one line

Comment: Please show us a sample of the HTML that you are accessing with this code and explain what you need to accomplish.

Comment: And yes - I know, it's horrible. But I'm doing my best dealing with a bunch on non-coders.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0]` [is just a bad idea... always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474). Use `document.querySelector("td")` instead.

Comment: Will try that, Scott :)

Comment: <td class="userNameClass" theusername="TROLLNAMEHERE" category="11" style="cursor:pointer;"><span style="font-weight:bold;color:#8899aa;">name</span></td>

Comment: Charlietfl - Supposedly I can have more but code from here does not work in the extension. Evidently he's had complaints. The alternative would be Java-Injector but obviously I am javascript-inexperienced - assuming the java does not actually mean Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line to hide the content:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("td[theUserName=madmax]")].forEach(e=>e.style.display = 'none');
```

To remove the `<td>`:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("td[theUserName=madmax]")].forEach(e=>e.remove());
```

Comment: Trying this one now

Comment: That line looks really sweet. But Codify is being a pain. I will take the above and try it with a different editor and message the dev. Thank you all so much! Especially you, Emeeus.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you to iterate through all `<td>` elements to search for one with `theUserName` attribute with value `madmax`, then make that element invisible. That can be achieved with:

```
for(TdElement of document.getElementsByTagName("td")) {
  if (TdElement.getAttribute("theUserName") == "madmax") {
    TdElement.style.visiblity = "hidden";
  }
}
```

Condensed to a single line, this is:

`for(TdElement of document.getElementsByTagName("td")) if TdElement.getAttribute("theUserName") == "madmax") TdElement.style.visiblity = "hidden"`

Comment: Not a good idea to omit the `{}`, it's just an invitation for bugs.

Comment: Good point. The answer provided by @Emeeus is much more succinct as well.

Comment: Which errors? I advise using Emeeus's solution, it's cleaner than mine.

Comment: Thank you for the effort guys! StackOverflow has always been a great place for good advice.